# NSRegularExpression doesn't match

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm making a regular expression for the following line:

```
Table 'Joella VIII' 6-max Seat #4 is the button
```

So far, I've got this:

```
self.tableDetailsRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Table '[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' [0-9]+-max Seat #[0-9]+ is the button" options:NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace error:nil];

if([self.tableDetailsRegex numberOfMatchesInString:line options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, line.length)] == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", line);
}
```

So, my regular expression is:

```
Table '[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' [0-9]+-max Seat #[0-9]+ is the button
```

And I'm sure the selected line comes by at some point, because I'm printing all the lines a bit further in my code...

Comment: FWIW,  if I copy/paste your pattern and test string into my tool, it does match. Problem relative to the `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the options you are using. From the [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW38), `NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace` means that whitespace and anything after a `#` in the regular expression will be ignored. With that option enabled, the regular expression acts like this:

```
Table'[A-Za-z0-9]*'[0-9]+-maxSeat
```

You probably want to pass 0 for the options, so that none of them get enabled.

```
self.tableDetailsRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Table '[A-Za-z0-9 ]*' [0-9]+-max Seat #[0-9]+ is the button" options:0 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression does match your string.  Try it in this [online matcher](http://regexpal.com/).

The problem is the option you pass: [NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW14) which causes the match to ignore white space and # signs plus anything following the # in the regular expression, which you don't want.  Pass zero for the options.